# Find the next three terms in the sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

This sequence consists of triplets; each triplet is linked to each other.

> $1,36,8,2,48,4,3,60,0,\text{X},\text{X},\text{X}$

The three $\text{X}$'s signify the missing numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next triplet is

> 3,72,6

because

> we are counting up in multiples of 6: 18, 24, 30, ... and for each we are splicing *twice the number* between its two digits.

(Thanks to @NoLand'sMan for pointing out in comments that I can't count.)

Comment: Did you mean 72 instead of 84?

Comment: @NoLand'sMan Duh, of course I do. Will fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> 4 72 -4

because

> base on each term relation in the triplet

Comment: Please explain exactly what you believe the "relation" to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another offering.

> Arranging the triplets in rows
>
>  $1 \space 36 \space 8$
>  $2 \space 48 \space 4$
>  $3 \space 60 \space 0$
>
>  It can be seen that:
>  The first column is the row/triplet number so the next is $4$.
>  The second column is an arithmetic progression so the next is $72$.
>  The third column is an arithmetic progression but I want to avoid a negative number and duplicating [another answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83832/).
>
>  So I multiply the first 3 digits in each row and take the modulus of 10.
>
>  $1 \space 36 \space (1 \cdot 3 \cdot 6) \equiv 8 \pmod {10}$
>  $2 \space 48 \space (2 \cdot 4 \cdot 8) \equiv 4 \pmod {10}$
>  $3 \space 60 \space (3 \cdot 6 \cdot 0) \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$
>
>  and then
>
>  $4 \space 72 \space (4 \cdot 7 \cdot 2) \equiv 6 \pmod {10}$
>
>  So my answer is: $4 \space 72 \space 6$